# Не понятный отступ в низу

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var d = document;
var wrap = d.querySelector('.wrap');
var items = d.querySelector('.items');
var itemCount = d.querySelectorAll('.item').length;
var scroller = d.querySelector('.scroller');
var pos = 0;
var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');

function setTransform() {
 items.style[transform] = 'translate3d(' + (-pos * items.offsetWidth) + 'px,0,0)';
}

function prev() {
 pos = Math.max(pos - 1, 0);
 setTransform();
}
function next() {
 pos = Math.min(pos + 1 , itemCount - 1);
 setTransform();
}
```

```css
html{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: auto; 
}

a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}


img{
    border: 0;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 0;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
/*
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 430px;
*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #689cd2;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Uni Sans;
}


.header-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-item{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.header-item:hover{
    background-color: #ff9900;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.headerlogo{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.headerButton{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sideBar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 630px;
    width: 160px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d7dbdd;
    background-color: #fcfdfd;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sideBar-item{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sideBar-item:hover{
    background-color: #eef3f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.sideBar-item a{
    color: #689cd2;
}

sideBar-item a:visited{
    color: #689cd2;
}

main{
    display: flex;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    background-color: #333;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrap{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}

button{
    width: 30px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

button:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}



.scroller{
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.items{
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item{
    padding: 30px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0.0.0.0.5);
}

.galery{
    padding: .5vw;
    font-size: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    display: flex;
}

.galery div{
    flex: auto;
    width: 237px;
    margin: .5vw;
}

.galery div img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .galery div{margin: 0;}
    .galery {padding: 0;}
}

.galery:hover img{
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: 0.8s opacity;
}

.galery:hover img:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.8s opacity;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flaxbox.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-section">
        <div class="heaer-item headerlogo">
            OS
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="flexbox.html">Главная</a>
        </div>
           <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Новости</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">События</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Лайфхауи</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Технологии</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Бизнесс</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="header-section">
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Регистрация</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-item headerButton">
            <a href="#">Вход</a>
        </div> 
        </div>
</div>
<main>
    <div class="sideBar">
        <div class="sideBar-section">
            <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Моя страница</a></div>
             <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Друзья</a></div>
              <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Ответы</a></div>
               <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Групы</a></div>
                <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="photo.html">Фото</a></div>
                 <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Музыка</a></div>
                  <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Игры</a></div>
                  <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Закладки</a></div>
        </div>
       <div class="sideBar-section">
            <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Дни рождения</a></div>
             <div class="sideBar-item"><a href="#">Уведомления</a></div>
       </div>
    </div>


   <div class="wrap">
       <h1>Slider</h1>
       <div class="slider">
           <button onclick="prev()">&laquo;</button>
           <div class="scroller">
               <ul class="items">
                   <li class="item" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/351448/pexels-photo-351448.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb)"></li>
                   <li class="item" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/356807/pexels-photo-356807.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb)"></li>
                   <li class="item" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/346908/pexels-photo-346908.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb)"></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <button onclick="next()">&raquo;</button>
       </div>
   </div>
    
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scrypt.js"></script>



<!--
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Вт вот этот отступ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не воспроизводится

Comment: @Cheg Имеешь в виду отступы не воспроизводятся?

Comment: да, отступы, что вы показали на изображении не воспроизводятся. Если у вас воспроизводятся, то  в каком браузере и на каком разрешении смотрите. Если в примере у вас тоже не воспроизводится то скорее всего ошибка была синтаксическая, вроде незакрытого тега.